# request a variable by comparing two strings in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I wants to compare two variables for checking if this comparison as a variable is empty.
I know its very confusing but i don´t know how explain it better. Here a small example code:

```
declare -a List=("human" "animal")
sqlhuman="SELECT * FROM example;"

for i in "${List[@]}"
do
   if[ -n "sql$i"];then
       #execute sql
   else
       #do nothing
   fi
done
```

In this case the script check if "sqlhuman" and "sqlanimal" are empty. Of course they are not empty. Both has more then 1 letters. I want them as pointer to variables and check if they are empty.

So what i need is dynamical build of variable directories. For example on first iterator he should check if $sqlhuman is empty.

Comment: With bash: `if [ -n $("sql$i") ]`

Comment: @RaphaMex No; you are trying to execute a command named `sqlhuman` in that case.

Comment: You're right, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the *string* `sqlhuman` is empty, not the contents of the variable named `sqlhuman`. Use indirect parameter expansion:

```
var="sql$i"
if [ -n "${!var}" ]; then
```

That said, a function would be a much cleaner approach.

```
do_sql () {
    case $1 in
        human) echo "running sql for human" ;;
        animal) echo "running sql for animal" ;;
        *) echo "doing nothing" ;;
    esac
}

for i in "${List[@]}"; do
    do_sql "$i"
done
```

Comment: Yes the background of my mistake i know. I already explained it in my question. This works fine for me. But what is ! before var are doing?

Comment: That's the syntax for indirect parameter expansion. `${!var}` expands `$var`, then expands the variable whose name is in the result. If `var` is `sqlhuman`, then `${!var}` and `${sqlhuman}` expand to the same thing.

Comment: awesome! Thank you a lot